# krajee image upload plugin file extension message not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to upload image using krajee image upload plugin. but msgInvalidFileType not working on it.

krajee - https://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-options#msgInvalidFileExtension

**My code is bellow**

```
(function ($) {
            var selected_file_count = $('#is_file_uploaded');
            $("#file-1").fileinput({
                theme: 'explorer-fas',
                uploadUrl: "<?php echo base_url('exampleurl.php')?>",
                uploadAsync: true,
                overwriteInitial: false,
                fileActionSettings: {showDrag: false},
                minFileCount: 1,
                maxFileCount: 1,
                initialPreviewShowDelete: false,
                initialPreviewAsData: true,
                previewFileIcon: '<i class="fas fa-file"></i>',
                allowedFileExtensions: ['stl'],
                msgInvalidFileType: "Only stl files are supported."
                showUpload: false
            }).on('filebatchselected', function (event, numFiles, label) {
                $('#file-1').fileinput('upload');
            }).on('filebatchuploadcomplete', function (event, files, extra) {
                alert('Successfully uploaded');
            }).on('filedeleted', function (event, files, extra) {
            }).on('fileselect', function (event, numFiles, label) {
            });
            $('.fileinput-remove').addClass('hide');
        })(jQuery);
```

**My inpul type**

```
<input id="file-1" type="file" class="file" name="stl_file">
```

[image]

i also try **msgInvalidFileExtension** but this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is working for me**

```
.on('filebatchselected', function (event, numFiles, label) {
    if ($('.kv-fileinput-error').text().length == 0) {
        $('#file-1').fileinput('upload');
    }
})
```

[image]